# use R to retrieve public link to dropbox file

Tags: r, dropbox

I have several R functions that save files to drop box (mainly plots).  This enables me to share them on the web as a web address.  These functions will save the plots and automatically open them and the dropbox directory they're located in.  I'm all about laziness/efficiency (depending on your perspective) and, unfortunately, when I finish I still have to right click the file I created and then Dropbox/copy public link.  I would like to have R retrieve this public link, if possible (once I have that I'll be even lazier and have it write right to the clipboard).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use the [CLI interface of Dropbox](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI) and the **system** (i'm in linux) function of R.

I have a png (interpolation.png) file on my public folder, if I want the public link I can do something like this :

```
getwd()
[1] "/home/ahmadou/Dropbox/Public"

system('dropbox puburl interpolation.png ', intern = TRUE)
[1] "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8750577/interpolation.png"
```

Hope this help

Comment: I'm adding "dropbox interface" to the list of packages I should write one day.

Comment: @Richie Cotton : It will be a great idea since many people use it...a first step would be to dig into the python code of command line interface (http://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py)

Comment: Any idea of how to extend this to Windows?

Comment: @TylerRinker : You can download the python code on my comment above adn use the **shell** function in place of **system** to execute the script...(not tested since I don't have a window machine)

Comment: can i use the dropbox public url as a source in HTML5: <audio src="http:\\dropxboxABCEFD.mp3"> ?

Comment: Congrats, you have now 2013 reps, happy new year 2013 :)